# Calculating the equilibrium value of a discrete time system in matrix form?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

**Context:**

I am hoping to calculate the equilibrium of the following discrete time system.

$x(t)=Ax(t-1)$, where

```
A={{0.15,0.15,0.1,0.2,0.4},{0,0.55,0,0,0.45},{0.3,0.05,0.05,0,0.6},{0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0},{0,0.3,0,0,0.7}};
```

I have little experience working with matrices, let alone in Mathematica. Is there an easy way to use Mathematica to calculate the equilibrium values of ${x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}$ to which this system converges?

Comment: What does the + mean above the x on the left?

Comment: Hi @BiologistLearningMath! What does the notation $x^+$ mean here? $x_{t+1}$?

Comment: @bills I updated the notation; sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @ChrisK Updated the notation; apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Each row of $A$ sums to 1, meaning this is a [right stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). In that case the standard recursion would be $x_t = x_{t-1} A$ with $A$ on the right, and where $x_t$ are row vectors of probabilities. (Of course, there can also be good reasons to study $x_t = Ax_{t-1}$.)

Comment: @user293787 In population biology, we often use $x_t=Ax_{t-1}$ ([Leslie matrix models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_matrix)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

X = Array[x, 5];

A = {{0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4}, {0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45}, {0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 
    0.6}, {0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7}};
```

Using [`MatrixPower`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html),

```
Xeq1 = Limit[MatrixPower[A, n], n -> Infinity] . X // Chop

(* {0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 
 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5]} *)
```

Using exact numbers,

```
Xeq2 = Limit[MatrixPower[A // Rationalize, n], n -> Infinity] . X

(* {(2 x[2])/5 + (3 x[5])/5, (2 x[2])/5 + (3 x[5])/5, (2 x[2])/5 + (3 x[5])/5, (
  2 x[2])/5 + (3 x[5])/5, (2 x[2])/5 + (3 x[5])/5} *)
```

Using [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html),

```
Xeq3 = FixedPoint[A . # &, A] . X // Chop

(* {0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 
 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5], 0.4 x[2] + 0.6 x[5]} *)

Xeq1 == Xeq2 == Xeq3

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** The result indicates that at equilibrium, all of the `x[i]` are equal and depend only on the initial values of `x[2]` and `x[5]`

Let

```
SeedRandom[1234];

x[2] = RandomReal[]; x[5] = RandomReal[];
```

Then

```
X

(* {x[1], 0.876608, x[3], x[4], 0.521964} *)

Xeq = FixedPoint[A . # &, A] . X // Chop

(* {0.663822, 0.663822, 0.663822, 0.663822, 0.663822} *)

% == ConstantArray[((2 x[2])/5 + (3 x[5])/5), 5]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Why do we get a list of the same expressions as opposed to a list {0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.6}?

Comment: @BiologistLearningMath - See edit

Answer (score 6):

Such a system for arbitrary $A$ has only the trivial equilibrium $x=0$.  In this case you're lucky that the dominant eigenvalue of $A$ is 1.  In this case, the equilibrium is proportional to the corresponding eigenvector.

```
Eigenvalues[A]
(* {1., 0.537714, 0.25, 0.209002, -0.0467153} *)
Eigenvectors[A][[1]]
(* {-0.447214, -0.447214, -0.447214, -0.447214, -0.447214} *)
```

This is only defined up to a constant set by the initial conditions.  But the relative abundance in the different classes will be equal.

Answer (score 6):

There is a chance that I am answering the wrong question, but if $A$ is to be interpreted as a right stochastic matrix (which makes sense since the entries are nonnegative and row sums are equal to $1$) then the stationary vector would be that row vector $v$ for which $v = vA$ with entries summing to 1.

If one wants to use Mathematica's built-in tools for such things, one can use:

```
initial={.2,.2,.2,.2,.2}; (* essentially irrelevant for what we do *)
proc=DiscreteMarkovProcess[initial,A]
```

The stationary distribution is then given by

```
stat=StationaryDistribution[proc];
```

This returns a somewhat ugly object, but to get plain numbers, one can use

```
Chop[PDF[stat][Range[5]]]
(* {0,0.4,0,0,0.6} *)
```

so the stationary distribution would be 40 percent in the second state, 60 percent in the fifth state.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, the result depends on whether you have `x[n]==A.x[n-1]` or `x[n]==x[n-1].A`. Assuming the latter (this idea works either way) you can consider the fixed point equation `x==x.A`. This can be rewritten as `Transpose[A].x-x==0`. SO you can solve it by finding a nontrivial null space `Transpose[A]-IdentityMatrix[Length[A]]`.

```
amat = {{0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4}, {0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45}, {0.3, 
    0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.6}, {0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7}};
nullvec = 
  NullSpace[Transpose@amat - IdentityMatrix[Length[amat]]][[1]];
Chop[nullvec/Total[Abs[nullvec]]]

(* Out[370]= {0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.6} *)
```

I think this is simpler than other approaches insofar as it reduces to relatively simple linear algebra (at least if one squints and ignores details of the numerics).