# Am I calculating the limit of this discrete time system correctly?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

**Background**

I have the following discrete-time system:

```
(*System: x(t+1) = Ax(t)*)

(*Conditions: Q1+Q2=1; Q1 >= 0; Q2 >= 0*)
    
A={{Q1,1-Q1},{Q2,1-Q2}};
```

**Problem**

I am trying to calculate the equilibrium that this system converges to. Using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274367/calculating-the-equilibrium-value-of-a-discrete-time-system-in-matrix-form) method, I am doing the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Q2=1-Q1;
V = Array[x, 2];
A={{Q1,1-Q1},{Q2,1-Q2}};
Veq4 = Limit[MatrixPower[A // Rationalize, n], n -> Infinity,Assumptions->{0<=Q1<=1}] . V
```

**Question**

Does this method suffice for calculating the final value that the system converges to?

Comment: Is there any condition for s1 ?

Comment: @userrandrand Sorry, s1 was not supposed to be there! I fixed the equation.

Comment: You can copy paste if that s1 was there because you typed the equations.

Comment: @userrandrand The equations are correct now; thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: You can remove the If in the result if you use Assumptions -> {0 < Q1 < 1}. then you can consider separately the case Q1==0 and Q1==1.

Comment: But yes that works. You can also use the Eigenvalues method in the answer you linked.

Comment: @userrandrand Thank you for the help! For the case of $Q1=0$, I am getting an output of Undetermined. Is this correct?

Comment: If `Q1==1` then `A` is the identity matrix and every vector is a fix point or equilibrium. If `Q1==0` then there is `(-1)^n` so `A^n` does not have a limit.

Comment: Sorry more explicitly there is a `(-1)^n` in the components of `A^n` (also in the eigenvalues) and so `A^n` has no limit. That said, I think you would have a better feeling for the equations if you did this one by hand using the eigenvalue method.

Comment: Would be simpler to replace `Q2` with `1-Q1`. And `{1,1}` will very clearly be a fixed point eigenvector.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think how clear it is that `{1,1}` was an eigenvector depends on one's experience. A somewhat clean way to  find the eigenvectors here would be to notice that `A` can be decomposed in terms of the Identity matrix and the reflection/involution {{0,1},{1,0}} ( one of the Pauli matrices). The eigenvectors of `A` are then the eigenvectors of {{0,1},{1,0}} which might be easier to work with. In particular as the result of `{{0,1},{1,0}}.}{a,b}` is {b,a} then indeed taking a=b results in an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @userrandrand It's clear because one can verify it using `{{q,1-q},{1-q,q}}.{1,1}=={1,1}`. That is, no eigenstuff need be computed.

Comment: Recalling that  {{0,1},{1,0}} is an involution, the other eigenvalue is -1 (it has to be a root of the minimal annihilating polynomial X^-1) and so one finds that another eigenvector is {1,-1}. As the corresponding eigenvalue of `A` from the eigenvector {1,1} is 1 and the eigenvalues of `A^n` are the n'th power of the eigenvalues of A then one finds that {1,1} is an eigenvector of eigenvalue 1 for all n.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau agreed it is easy to check that {1,1} is an eigenvector but I do not consider it trivial to notice that visually just from looking at the components without prior experience (mental abstract pattern matching). That is, I consider it somewhat easy to check but not necessarily easy to find the eigenvector just by staring at the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**modified**

Mathematica is able to visualize the result.
Try

```
An = Asymptotic[MatrixPower[A , n], n -> Infinity];
(*{{1/2 + 1/2 (-1 + 2 Q1)^n,1/2 - 1/2 (-1 + 2 Q1)^n},
{1/2 - 1/2 (-1 + 2 Q1)^n,1/2 + 1/2 (-1 + 2 Q1)^n}}*)

Show[Table[Plot[ An // Flatten // Evaluate , {Q1, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,PlotStyle -> RandomColor[] ], {n, 5, 10}]]
```

[image]

Plot shows `Limit[A^n,n->Infinity] =={{1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}` for `0<Q1<1`

Case `Q1==0`:

```
Table[An /. Q1 -> 0 , {n, 7, 10}] //Simplify[#, Element[n,PositiveIntegers]] &
(* {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}*)
```

Case `Q1==1`:

```
An /. Q1 -> 1 // Simplify[#, Element[n, PositiveIntegers]] &
(*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)
```

Comment: `Asymptotic` did not do anything on my computer. Also it should be `MatrixPower[A, n]` not `MatrixPower[A^n, n]` nor `A^n` in `Limit`.  I also do not understand why you used `Asymptotic` when later `An` is evaluated on values of `n` like `n=5`

Comment: @userrandrand Thanks for your reply, I 'll correct my answer. `Asymptotic[...,n]` gives an expression depending on `n`.

Comment: Hi, there is a remaining `Limit[A^n,n->Infinity]` in the answer whereas it should be `MatrixPower[A, n]` rather than `A^n`. Asymptotic[...,n] does give an n dependent expression but I did not understand why the values of n were rather small. In any case, for this particular `A` at least, `Asymptotic[...,n->Infinity]` gives the same result as computing `MatrixPower[A , n]` directly and so it does not seem needed.

Comment: Also, I do not know if users are updated when an answer is updated. I saw a user here that left a comment on a question after editing their answer. As the answer was accepted it might be good to make sure OP is informed that the limit matrix was not 0 `for 0<Q1<1`.